# Check if there is a duplicate value then pop up a message google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an html input for a certain ID Number. If the user inputs the ID Number, it will check in the google script if it already exists. If it already exist, it will pop up a message with the ID number in it.

This is the html input for the ID:
[image]

This is the screen shot of my google sheets ID List:

[image]

for my html code:

```
   <div class="row">
      <!-- ID NUMBER -->
      <div class="input-field col s4">
         <input id="idnum" type="text" class="validate">
         <label for="idnum">Identification Number</label>
      </div> <!-- CLOSE ROLL NUMBER FIELD -->
   </div> <!-- CLOSE ROW -->
```

for javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("idnum").addEventListener("input",getID);

function getID(){

var IdNum = document.getElementById("idnum").value;

  if(IdNum.length === 5){
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateID).getID(IdNum);
  }
}

function updateID(idn){
  alert("ID Number: " + idn + " already exist.");
  //document.getElementById("idnum").value = "";
}

</script>
```

for google script:

```
function getID(IdNum){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Test_Data");  
  var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

  var IdList = data.map(function (r){return r[0];})  

  var Idpos = IdList.indexOf(IdNum);

  if (Idpos > -1)
  {
     return IdList[Idpos];
  } 
}
```

I can't display a pop up message with the ID number entered in the html. It will always say "undefined".

[image]

Since I put `document.getElementById("idnum").value = "";`  in the javascript, it always delete the input. What I need to is if the input ID number in the hmtl exist it will pop a message saying the ID exists but if it does not exist, it will retain the input value and not erase it.

For example, if I input "12345" in the html, a pop up message will say "ID Number: 12345 already exist." then it will delete the input value. And if I input "55555" which is not yet in the sheets, no pop up message and the value will not be erased or set to blank. Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Where is `undefined` being returned from--is `IdList[Idpos] === undefined`? Is `rollNum`/`IdNum` an error from adapting an example for SO, or is that in your actual code? What value does `getID()` return when `Idpos <= -1`? If you don't define a return value...

Comment: I think `getID()` returned "undefined". Sorry I'm a newbie in javascript and google script. I only modified the code I got from youtube.

Comment: Whatever the value returned from `getID()` is will be the `idn` in `updateID()`. Make sure that `getID()` returns the ID--or, handle it some other way if there's no ID to return.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I just want to know how to make it not erase the value if it does not exist because I think there's an error in my code, and I'm still figuring where. Coz if I enter a value which is not yet existing, it will still pop up the message and set the input to blank.

Comment: I think what you're trying to say is that if `idn` exists, you want to replace `idnum`'s value, but if it doesn't, you want to do something else? Google 'conditional statements in Javascript', specifically, see how to use an if...else statement.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my google script to:

```
function getID(IdNum){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Test_Data");  
  var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var dJoin = data.join().split(",");
  var myId = dJoin.indexOf(IdNum);

  if (myId > -1){
    return IdNum;
  } else {
    return "unavailable";
  }
}
```

and my javascript to:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("idnum").addEventListener("input",getID);

function getID(){

var IdNum = document.getElementById("idnum").value;

  if(IdNum.length === 5){
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateID).getID(IdNum);
  }
}

function updateID(idn, IdNum){
  var IdNum = document.getElementById("idnum").value;

  if (idn === IdNum) {
  alert("ID Number: " + idn + " already exist.");
  document.getElementById("idnum").value = "";
  }
}
</script>
```